# Redirecting(>) h5dump output to text file causes data loss

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, hdf5

I have a bash script that runs the following command:

h5dump --noindex particle_pos.6400_acetone > tempPythonFile.txt

The contents of the hdf5 file, particle_pos.6400_acetone, is a collection of x,y,z coordinates like a sample shown below.

```
HDF5 "particle_pos.6400_acetone" { GROUP "/" {    DATASET "particle position" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "x";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "y";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "z";
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 7372815 ) / ( 7372815 ) }
      DATA {
         {
            0.0985972,
            0.0051215,
            0.000543894
         },
         {
            0.0986334,
            0.00520195,
            0.000408405
         },
```

The file should look like the text above all the way through, but when I go to the end of the text file I see the following.

```
},
         {
            ,
            -0.162017,

         },
         {
            ,
            ,

         },
         {
            ,
            ,

         },
         {
            ,
            ,
```

To me it looks like something is happening that is dropping data because there is occasionally a floating point number in the sea of blank entries.

I haven't had an issue with this command on smaller data sets, but I started seeing data missing from the tempPythonFile.txt file when my data set contained 7372815 elements.

Is there a more accepted method for getting HDF5 data out to a text file? Is the redirect(>) command not suited for large amounts of data?

Thank you

Comment: Is some of the output written to stderr? If so then you should also redirect that to your output file.

Comment: I did that and didn't see anything additional get printed.

Comment: Redirection does not modify/filter any command output: it simply _redirects_ all the output (usually directed to the standard output file) into another file.
I suggest you to have a better look to your input dataset and/or to the manual of _h5dump_

Comment: I have sent the file to the HDF5 Group because they expressed interest in trying to reproduce the issue. I'll update when more information comes along.

Comment: I did hear back from the HDF5 group, and they did find that it was an issue with the version of HDF5 that I was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did hear back from the HDF5 group, and they did find that it was an issue with the version of HDF5 that I was using.